# SFML TCP Socket Sending causes lag spikes

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp, sfml

This gets called every frame at 30 FPS (as it should be), but every 10 seconds or so a massive lagspike occurs. The spikes tend to last 5 seconds then it runs smooth again. What am I doing wrong?

```
socketsSent++;
sf::TcpSocket socket;
socket.connect(ip, atoi(serverInfo[5].c_str()));
std::string data;
data = "X:" + std::to_string((int)objects["player"].getPosition().x) + ":Y:" + std::to_string((int)objects["player"].getPosition().y);
socket.send(data.c_str(), data.length() + 1);
```

Comment: You are connecting, sending that message and disconnecting 30 times per second?

Comment: Please make sure to read the [official tutorials](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/#network-module) and the [official FAQ](http://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#networking) and actually think about what your code does. Knowing how networking (TCP) works is also rather important...

Answer (score 1):

Keep the connection open across these calls. A TCP connect requires three packets to be exchanged, and a disconnect requires four, so you have a packet overhead of up to 7 times if you connect and disconnect each time.

However, it's not a real-time protocol. You must expect some lags here and there.